# Recursive CTE in H2: No data returned

Tags: sql, h2, common-table-expression

I am trying to convert a proprietary Oracle `CONNECT BY` query into a standard SQL query that will run on H2, and generate the same data *in the same order*.

This is the Oracle query, which works:

```
SELECT id, name, parent
        FROM myschema.mytable 
        START WITH id = 1 
        CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent
```

This is what I've come up - however, it returns no rows in the `ResultSet`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE T(id, name, parent, path) AS (
    SELECT id, name, '' AS parent, id AS path 
    FROM myschema.mytable WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ou.id, ou.name, ou.parent, 
        (T.path + '.' + CAST (ou.id AS VARCHAR)) AS path 
    FROM T INNER JOIN myschema.mytable AS ou ON T.id = ou.parent
) SELECT id, name, parent FROM T ORDER BY path
```

The initial row, and the related rows, both exist in the table.

I am not using H2's Oracle compatibility mode (which doesn't support CONNECT BY, by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a problem with either the Anorm database access library or the JDBC driver not substituting a query parameter correctly (the query substitution was not shown in the question, because I assumed it wasn't relevant).

Comment: Unfortunately, the H2 implementation of recursive queries does not currently support parameters (see [recursive queries - limitations](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries)). I think that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me, for both H2 as well as PostgreSQL ([this you can test online using the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e7d13/2)). I had to make a few changes and assumptions (see below):

```
create table mytable(id int, name varchar(255), parent int);
insert into mytable values(1, 'root', null), (2, 'first', 1), 
(3, 'second', 1), (4, '2b', 3);

WITH RECURSIVE T(id, name, parent, path) AS (
SELECT id, name, 0 AS parent, 
    cast(id as varchar) AS path 
FROM mytable WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ou.id, ou.name, ou.parent, 
    (T.path || '.' || CAST (ou.id AS VARCHAR)) AS path 
FROM T INNER JOIN mytable AS ou ON T.id = ou.parent
) SELECT id, name, parent, path FROM T ORDER BY path
```

Changes:

- I assumed `id` and `parent` are integers. Because of that, I had to use `cast(id as varchar)` in the first select.
- I replace `+` with `||` when concatenating strings.
- I used `0 AS parent`.

Comment: Weird... I've based my query on this, and it works in the H2 console, but returns no data from my application - both are connected to the same database! Maybe the framework I'm using is subtly mangling the SQL somehow.