# Order rows with same table circular reference

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table which contains a foreign key which is linked to the table's primary key. The primary key column contains values from the foreign key column, and vice versa. (e.g. a child can be a parent, and a parent can be a child.). Actual string values are UUIDs, and the database is H2.

How to implement a select query in order to have the rows from the table ordered by the parents, which become children ? Tried a few implementations with left joins, but none worked.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/332033)

Example:

Values in the table:

Parent1        null
Child4         Parent3
Parent3        Child2
Parent5        Child4
Child2         Parent1

Desired query output:

parent1   null
child2    parent1
parent3   child2
child4    parent3
Parent5   child4

Regards.

Comment: MySQL does not have real support for recursive CTEs or hierarchical queries.  Hence, you would have to do this using a stored procedure.

Comment: Found the answer here. [CTE in H2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691379/recursive-cte-in-h2-no-data-returned)